# MockBean stubbing ineffective

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, mocking, mockito

I have a configuration class with a few MockBeans replacing actual beans in context for tests.

```
@Configuration
public class MyTestConfig {
    @MockBean
    private MyService myService;
}
```

I use those mocks in my tests:

```
@Import({ MyTestConfig .class })
public class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        ...
    }
}
```

First the idea was to add the stubbing in this `MyTestConfig` configuration class, so that the mock is pre-made for all tests, so I did it in a `@PostConstruct` method, and it worked just fine - the mock in test did return the expected value:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    when(myService.foo("say hello")).thenReturn("Hello world");
}
```

It turned out though, that constructing a pre-made mock suitable for all test can be tricky, so we decided to move the stubbing to tests.

```
@Test
public void aTest() {
    when(myService.foo("say hello")).thenReturn("Hello world");
}
```

And this doesn't work - the stubbed method returns `null`. We want to leave MockBeans in the configuration class, but stub them in tests, so any advice on why the stubbing is ineffective?

Spring Boot 2.0.5, Mockito 2.22.0

Comment: I'm actually surprised that `@MockBean` works in a configuration class as it shouldn't. Also the use of `@Import` on your test class is something you shouldn't be doing. If you want to globally mock beans you will need to create the mock yourself using `Mockito.mock` inside an `@Bean` method to have reliable mocking. Else use an `@Autowired` field in your testcase which you want to use the mocked instance. Also instead of `@Import` you should specify this in your `@SpringBootTest` or `@ContextConfiguration` as class to use for configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum The documentation of `@MockBean` states: _Can be used as a class level annotation or on fields in either @Configuration classes, or test classes that are @RunWith the SpringRunner_, so it's definitely supposed to work in configuration class. Defining a plain mock in @Bean method would be fine if the stubbing in test worked, but it doesn't, so that's not an option either.

Comment: If stubbing doesn't work you must be doing weird things. We use this literally in hundreds of testcases and works like a charm. Are you defining the correct stubbing for the actions you want to perform?

Comment: @M.Deinum Turns our my problem description is insufficient, because I skipped quite an important detail, but you did help me figure it out anyway. What I didn't say (aiming to keep it simple) is that my test is an `@WebMvcTest` with `@WithUserDetails`, and my service is a dependency of a custom `UserDetailsManager`. Spring Security makes the call to `UserDetailsManager` _before_ the actual test content. That's why the stubbing in test had no effect, and that's why it worked fine when the mock was stubbed in config's `@PostConstruct`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, stubbing should be performed inside their respective test cases (unless you have a test class that shares the stubbing scenarios but it all comes down to preference).

However, for creating `@MockBeans`, you would need to use a `@SpringBootTest` in order to get the actual beans replaced with mocks. This could be done as simply as this example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyTestClass testClass;
    @MockBean
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
      // testing....
  }

}
```

Comment: The bean _is_ actually replaced with a mock. `MockUtil.isMock(myService)` returns `true` in test. The only issue is that the stubbing performed in test has no effect.

Comment: Are you using `@SpringBootTest` and a `SpringRunner` to run your tests?

Comment: I figured it out, see my comments under the question. Thanks for help!